# ASP.NET HTML.LabelFor From Collection of Models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, html.labelfor

Ok im very new to ASP.NET 4.5 (giving PHP a break) and stuck with rendering a label.

I have a ViewModel that defines the necessary Models :

```
 public class TransactionsViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Area> Areas { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Mistake> Mistakes { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

Transaction is just another model with simple properties, now i want to display a label for one of the Transaction properties.

My View has the strong type TransactionsViewModel

```
@model AuditSystem.ViewModels.TransactionsViewModel
```

This means that the HTMLHelper has type of < TransactionsViewModel> when overriding.

The method prototyope im trying to create is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TClass, TValue>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
        IEnumerable<TClass> model,
        Expression<Func<TClass, TValue>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
```

Where < TModel> is TransactionsViewModel (strong typed) and < TClass> is  (Transaction)

This causes a problem when trying to call helper.LabelFor since that expectes an expression of Expression>, but i need to pass Func.

I tried to reconstruct an expression with the valid types, but get stuck on the call to the html.labelfor and typecasting wont work.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the output to be. Are you trying to create a label for the collection, or a property of an item in the collection. The first makes no sense since a `<label>` element is associated with a form control (clicking on its sets focus) and you can't have a form control for a collection

Comment: My ViewModel has a collection of Transaction. I want to display a label for Transaction.Property. I expect to call my override with:
html.labelfor(Model.Transactions, t => t.property)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why do you need to override LabelFor. You might try like this-

```
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Transactions.First().Property)
```

Update

Use FirstOrDefault instead of First to avoid exception.

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.FirstOrDefault().Property)
```

Comment: what happens if model.Transactions is empty?

Comment: will throw exception. Try @Html.LabelForm(model=>model.Transactions.FirstOrDefault().Property)

Comment: Yeah, i dont want to assume transactions always contains object because scenarios do exist where its empty. So i have to rebuild an expression that changes my TClass to a TModel so Html.Labelform can accept it. Problem will be TModel is a TransactionsViewModel and TClass is a Transaction.

Comment: Yes use FirstOrDefault(). This will work even if you dont pass the model to view.

Comment: I just thought this approach is hackish and tried to avoid it. I thought the best approach was an override. I was copying a function i found that did the same thing but for the DisplayFor. Not sure who downvoted but i hope they give a reason?